# Making sure my files are closed

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

I'm building a drive realtime app that creates and uses multiple drive files. I can delete, create, and load drive files. When I open them, I load them for realtime, then do some stuff and call doc.close(). After deleting files, I start getting 404 errors. If I delete more files, I get more 404 errors.

I'm closing all my files through realtime, is there something I'm also supposed to do to close it from drive before calling gapi.client.drive.files.delete? Is there any way I can check what files realtime thinks is open?

Here are examples of the URLs that are 404ing. Are otservice/test urls even part of the realtime-api?

```
GET https://drive.google.com/otservice/test?id=1BSgEjt1WPDDnw16ORScZ7dFuQMZGoLi…aaWnqrey54eGmmY4dsZ4tKY&lsq=1394278669132&gsi&MODE=init&zx=ih93606ahbd&t=1 404 (Not Found) api:86
GET https://drive.google.com/otservice/test?id=1s9MXdpWfG-nUy78Xrfdj4XHctMKO-Ob…aWnqrey54eGmmY4dsZ4tKY&lsq=1394278855069&gsi&MODE=init&zx=am1pjia79w4q&t=1 404 (Not Found) api:86
GET https://drive.google.com/otservice/test?id=1eUJForQ3np2Fg4JsQjJlfV-H_dmN8lv…aWnqrey54eGmmY4dsZ4tKY&lsq=1394278830127&gsi&MODE=init&zx=6oxohpw5biwc&t=1 404 (Not Found) api:86
GET https://drive.google.com/otservice/test?id=1eUJForQ3np2Fg4JsQjJlfV-H_dmN8lv…aaWnqrey54eGmmY4dsZ4tKY&lsq=1394278830139&gsi&MODE=init&zx=enxr78enfsc&t=1 404 (Not Found) api:86
GET https://drive.google.com/otservice/test?id=1BSgEjt1WPDDnw16ORScZ7dFuQMZGoLi…aWnqrey54eGmmY4dsZ4tKY&lsq=1394278669129&gsi&MODE=init&zx=9lmzxxgabw3v&t=1 404 (Not Found) api:86
GET https://drive.google.com/otservice/test?id=1s9MXdpWfG-nUy78Xrfdj4XHctMKO-Ob…aWnqrey54eGmmY4dsZ4tKY&lsq=1394278855080&gsi&MODE=init&zx=2838z2er02ai&t=1 404 (Not Found) api:86
GET https://drive.google.com/otservice/test?id=1s9MXdpWfG-nUy78Xrfdj4XHctMKO-Ob…aWnqrey54eGmmY4dsZ4tKY&lsq=1394278855085&gsi&MODE=init&zx=hsf4r3fptm31&t=1 404 (Not Found)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, these URLs are part of the Drive Realtime API: they are used to configure the connection from the Realtime server to the browser. A 404 error is consistent with the file being deleted.

Do you have some example code that you could share which reproduces this issue?

Thanks,
Brian (Drive Realtime API Engineer)

Comment: I just put together a sample showing it, and was able to repro the issue consistently. When I had items on my model, then closed the file and called delete, I would get 404 errors. If I didn't put anything on my root then it wouldn't give 404s. My guess is that close was trying to do work, but close is async and doesn't provide a callback, so calling delete on the file could mean that close wasn't finished. My consistent test doesn't work anymore, did you guys just fix something?